# Service worker - Storage Usage is not decreased after caches deletion

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, browser-cache

- All works fine with install , activate lifecycle when i change the version and click skipwaiting.
  Old caches deleted succefully from Cache Storage and Usage Storage decreased as expected.
- Somewhere in my app i send a message to sw and try to delete all caches programaticaly.
  The code is inside self.addEventListener('message')
  I see the event fired , i dont get any errors , i see the caches are removed from Cache Storage ,
  but the Usage Storage is not decreased at all, so it is continue growing with future fetch events

Any ideas how I can solve that problem (any alternative solutions or any possible service worker improvements) and where the problem is?

here is my sw.js file

```
const version = 0.01;
const STATIC_CACHE_NAME = `static-v_${version}`;
const DYNAMIC_CACHE_NAME = `dynamic-v_${version}`;

const STATIC_PATHS = [...somePaths];
const DYNAMIC_PATHS = [...somePaths];

// --- ON INSTALL HANDLER ---  ON INSTALL HANDLER ---  ON INSTALL HANDLER ---
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('[SW] Installing ServiceWorker...');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open(STATIC_CACHE_NAME)
      .then(cache => {
        console.log('[SW] Pre Cache', STATIC_CACHE_NAME);
        cache.addAll(STATIC_PATHS);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('[SW] Pre Cache catch method', error);
      })
  );
});

// --- ON ACTIVATE HANDLER ---  ON ACTIVATE HANDLER ---  ON ACTIVATE HANDLER ---
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  console.log('[SW] Activating ServiceWorker...');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(keysList => {
      const filteredKeysList = keysList.filter(key => {
        return [STATIC_CACHE_NAME, DYNAMIC_CACHE_NAME].every(name => key !== name);
      });
      return Promise.all(
        filteredKeysList.map(key => {
          console.log('[SW] Deleting Old Cache: ', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        })
      );
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

// --- ON FETCH HANDLERS ---  ON FETCH HANDLERS ---  ON FETCH HANDLERS ---
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const isPreCachePath = checkIfPreCachePath(event.request.url);
  const isDynamicCachePah = checkIfDynamicCachePah(event.request.url);
  // console.log('isPreCachePath', event.request.url);
  if (isPreCachePath) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request.url).then(result => {
        if (result) return result;
        return fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
    // event.respondWith(event.request.cache);
  } else if (isDynamicCachePah) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request.url).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          return result;
        }
        return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
          return caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
            cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
            return response;
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
});

// --- ON MESSAGE HANDLERS ---  ON MESSAGE HANDLERS ---  ON MESSAGE HANDLERS ---
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  // console.log('SW On Message);
  if (event.data.type === 'delete-caches') {
    caches
      .keys()
      .then(keysList => {
        return Promise.all(
          keysList.map(key => {
            console.log(`[SW] Deleting Cache: ${key}`);
            return caches.delete(key);
          })
        );
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('[SW] Caches Deleted');
        // Force update service worker
        // self.skipWaiting();
        // self.clients.claim();
        // self.registration.update();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('[SW] Deleting Caches Error: ', err);
      });
  }
});

function checkIfPreCachePath(url) {
  // some checks
} 

function checkIfDynamicCachePah(url) {
  // some checks
}
```